# How to check the values in a instance with Python?

Tags: python, member

I have a python class/object as follows.

```
class Hello:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None
        self.z = None


h = Hello()
h.x = 10
h.y = 20
# h.z is not set
```

I need to check if all the member variables are set (not None). How can I do that automatically?

```
for value in ??memeber variables in h??:
    if value == None:
        print 'value is not set'
```

Comment: You don't. You write the class in a way that cannot leave it uninitialized (unless someone is really out to break your *and* their code, of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Hello(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None
        self.z = None
    def is_all_set(self):
        return all(getattr(self, attr) is not None for attr in self.__dict__)
```

though, as @delnan said, you should prefer to make it impossible for the class to always be in a valid state (this is referred to as preserving "class invariants")

Answer (score 0):

> I need to check if all the member variables are set (not None).

Why?

You need the member variables in order to do some processing in the class.

```
class Hello:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None
        self.z = None
    def some_processing( self ):
        assert all( self.x is not None, self.y is not None, self.z is not None )
        # Now do the processing.
```